# Работа в фоновом режим Metro-приложений

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8

Доброго времени суток.

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы при сворачивании metro приложение продолжало работу в фоновом режиме?

Answer (score 3):

Ваше основное приложение [будет "заморожено"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977056.aspx), но вы можете [зарегистрировать фоновые задания](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977055.aspx).

Вот Микрософтовский [пример кода](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Task-Sample-9209ade9).